# Code for fetching a picture (bitmap) from gallery not working

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery

**MY SOLUTION:**  Ok some good answers.  This is what I came up with.  Not sure to answer my own question or put it here for proper stackoverflowness so if anyone knows please share.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case cameraData:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case SELECT_PICTURE:
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            File imgFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            break;
        }
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream); // compress
        byte[] ba = stream.toByteArray();
        image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

OK I have a path to picture in my gallery. I want to take that picture and turn it into a bundle so I can 64 encode it to upload to my server. here is my onActivityResult.  I have it working from taking a picture with the camera just not getting it from the gallery.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
            case cameraData:                
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                Log.e("picture","Take Picture");
                break;
            case SELECT_PICTURE:
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Log.e("picture",selectedImagePath);
                File imgFile = new  File(selectedImagePath);                    
                bmp = (Bitmap)     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Bundle extras1 = ((Cursor) imgFile).getExtras();
    //          bmp = (Bitmap) extras1.get("data");
                Log.e("picture","from Gallery");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

the base 64 code is not mine its from this site: http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/

getPath:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for getPath. Have you checked what is stored in the "SelectedImageUri" variable after you call getData()?

Comment: OK added getPath and what is returned is the path to the image from the gallery on the phone.  the toString of selectedImageUri is "content://media/external/images/media/153

Comment: Check the log just when you finish selecting the image from gallery

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to turn the bitmap into a bundle? And why do you want to turn the file into a base64 String before you upload?

[Here](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) and [here](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/) are examples that upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/3A5gMFsF

Seems to do what you want. Looks like when you get a file URI back you need to dig through some Content Resolvers to actually get the file itself.

```
Uri photoUri = data.getData();
    if (photoUri != null)
    {
    try {
          String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
          Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
          String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
          cursor.close();
          bMap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
          ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
          img.setImageBitmap(bMap_image);
```

Edit: The only difference I see between this version and your version is that this version doesn't convert the filePath into a File before calling BitMap.Decode. It calls BitmapFactory.decodeFile directly on the file path returned from the content resolover.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the bitmap to base64.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

byte[] dataToUpload = Base64.encode(bitmapdata , DEFAULT);
```

To convert the bitmap to Bundle use `bundle.putParcelable("dataToUpload", bitmap)`
and retireve it using `bundle.getParcelable("dataToUpload")`.